# Update a record if it already exists in access with vb

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to check if a client is already signed in. if he is, then the button will sign him out instead of adding a new record altogether and I'm struggling to find a solution.
this is the current code I'm using:

```
        Private Sub btnSignIn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSignIn.Click
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    '     cnn = cnn
    Try
        If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then 'open the database connection
            cnn.Open()
        End If

        If txtClientName.Text = Nothing Then            'check to see if the name field is empty
            MsgBox("Please enter a name to sign in")
            txtClientName.Focus()

        ElseIf txtDateTime.Text = Nothing Then          ' checks if timeslip is empty
            MsgBox("Please enter a valid time to sign in")
            txtDateTime.Focus()
        Else                                        'if no fields are empty proceed with code
            cmd.Connection = cnn
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO LogSheet (ClientName, SignInTime, CurrentDate)" &
                               "VALUES(?, ?, ?)"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txtClientName.Text.ToString.ToUpper)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", txtDateTime.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", Date.Now().ToShortDateString)

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            RefreshData()
            txtClientName.Clear()
            txtDateTime.Clear()

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & " - " & ex.Source)
        cnn.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

there is no validation there, but ive tried many different codes with no luck..
I simply want the script to check, if client is signed in, then give an error "Client already signed in" else if he signs out, just update the signout field
thanks

This is an image of what my program is[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQO9X.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the structure of your Database Table (LogSheet) to include the following fields. `ClientName`,`SignInTime`,`SignInRelation`,`SignOutTime`,`SignOutRelation`,`CurrentDate`

If the client is signed in then the `SignInTime` for today (CurrentDate) will have a value, you can then populate the value for `SignOutTime`.

This is one possible way you could code it:

This code is untested, but you should get the idea.

```
  Sub BtnSignIn_Click()
    If IsUserLoggedIn(txtClientName.Text) = True Then
        'Client has been logged in already. Do Action.
    Else

        'Client has not been logged in today. Do Action.
    End If
End Sub


Function IsUserLoggedIn(UserName As String) As Boolean
    Dim sql = "Select SignOutTime From LogSheet Where CurrentDate=@D AND ClientName=@C"

    Try
        Using cnn As New OleDbConnection
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, cnn)
                cnn.Open()
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@D", Today.Date.ToShortDateString)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C", UserName)
                Dim result = cmd.ExecuteScalar

                If result Is Nothing OrElse result Is DBNull.Value OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(result.ToString) Then
                    Return False
                Else
                    Return True
                End If

            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error: " & System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.Name, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: yeah I have thought about that.. possibly make life easier.. but if I wanted the challenge.. is there a way??

Comment: I don't see how you are checking to see if they are logged in or not with your current code? There are a couple of ways you could do it, small file in a specified folder, registry entry or db field.

Comment: all the program is going to do is, they will select their childs name on the list, click "Sign in" and the time and which parent dropped them off will be saved... when the parent picks them up I simply want to update the fields to say what time they got picked up at and which parent picked them up.. I just don't want duplicates. that way In the future I can lookup a date if I need to see what time a kid was picked up @  check the picture I put to give you a bit of an idea

Comment: But where is the code to check if they are actually logged in?

Comment: I don't know how that is the problem

Comment: thank you I have marked it as solved, I was wondering if you could give a little code example showing how you would use the relation fields? thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

You should insert *DateTime* values:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", DateTime.Parse(txtDateTime.Text))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", DateTime.Today)
```

Comment: thank you, I'm trying to get the basics to work before I clean up the rest haha. its a program for home use that's the worst part.